# i cant login to my Django User credentials

Tags: python, html, django

I following the tutorial of https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication
I already following that site step by step and now i have reached Login Template stage, but i've some problem that i cant login, Django tell me that 'Your username and password didn't match. Please try again. ' even though I login using valid credentials
[image]

my login.html

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style login.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
{% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didnt match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesnt have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

    <div class="loginbox">
      <img src="{% static 'avatar.png' %}" class="avatar">
      <h1>Login Here</h1>
      <form method="post" action="{% url 'login'%}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Username</p>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="{{ next }}">
        <a href="">Dont have an account</a>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to share the login code as well. Also FYI your `<head>` and `<body>` tags are incorrect. The head and body need to be seperated. For example:
`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. The `title` and `link` need to remain in the head and the rest needs to stay in the body.

Comment: I'm really sorry Tom, that was my fault, i already fixed it

Comment: How are you getting the form field name in your html

Comment: @ngawang13 hey its work, i just realized that i have to write {{ form.username }} and {{ form.password}} thanks bro